# How can I tell which of the two forms is submitted in Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have a `log_in` and `sign_up` form in my home page. The `log_in` is set to display by default and the `sign_up` comes to view when a user clicks on **Sign Up** button. The two toggles, depending on the button a user clicks.

```
from django import forms

class LogInForm(forms.Form):
    pass
class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    pass
```

Both form calls the same view - `index_view()`.

Comment: Why not just have them call different views?

Comment: I can do that but I need them to submit to home page and still `redirect` to the same page. I think this can be done. I just can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong place for this. Django can't tell which form is submitted unless you give it some information in the POST. The *best* place to do this is in the submit button, which you can give a name and value to like any other form element.

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    {{ login_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="login">
</form>

<form action="." method="POST">
    {{ signup_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="signup" value="signup">
</form>
```

And in the view, all you need to do is check which input is in the POST:

```
if 'login' in request.POST:
    # do something with login_form
else:
    # do something with signup_form
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is add GET parameter to url and check it in the view:

```
<form action="{% url index %}?action=login">
```

and in the view

```
def index_view(request):
    action = request.GET.get('action', '')
    if action == 'login':
        ...
```